# Securing Kibana for an internet facing startup

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5, xpack, elasticsearch-x-pack

New to Kibana & not an expert in web security. We're trying to build a small startup in which we're leveraging Kibana 5.x for our backoffice analysts for data exploration. This is a webapp and will be accessible over the internet.
Also, X-PACK security (though promising) may not be an option for us purely because of cost.

I''d like to summarize my thoughts and get them validated by professionals out here.

- Firstly, I'm thinking of putting Elasticsearch behind a firewall so that only my APP server and Kibana server could access - ES is now secure.
- I'm thinking of fronting Kibana using a Reverse Proxy (Apache or Nginx) and apply basic authentication. And everything will be over HTTPS.
- I'll only allow GET requests to Kibana through this Reverse Proxy so that the users can read only.

Does this have any gap? Also I'm wondering if Kibana makes a direct call to Elasticsearch from it's Javascript running on the browser? If this is true then we would have another potential backdoor to get to ES. What should be done if this is true.

Comment: Do you know this plugin: https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard-kibana-plugin

Comment: Thank you. Appears like what I was after. I'll play with this a bit more. Cheers!